# Firing model events in Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the 'saved' event to fire on a model. I thought I had it working and it is to some extent. I'm listening to 3 different models and it's only working on one. The 'Attribute' model in my code below. Is there any reason why it would only work on one and why on that one?

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Clients\Attribute;
use App\Clients\Lead;
use App\Clients\Member;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{

    Attribute::saved(function ($attribute) {
            $meta = \App\Clients\ClientMeta::firstOrCreate(['client_id' => $attribute->mem_id, 'meta_name' => 'profile_updated']);
            $meta->meta_value = time();
            $meta->save();
        });

    Lead::saved(function ($lead) {
        if($lead->converted == 1)
        {
            $meta = \App\Clients\ClientMeta::firstOrCreate(['client_id' => $lead->id, 'meta_name' => 'profile_updated']);
            $meta->meta_value = time();
            $meta->save();
        }
        });

    Member::saved(function ($member) {
            $meta = \App\Clients\ClientMeta::firstOrCreate(['client_id' => $member->member_lead_trace, 'meta_name' => 'profile_updated']);
            $meta->meta_value = time();
            $meta->save();
        });

}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
```

}

Comment: have you tried to just add them to their own model boot method rather than the service provider ect

Comment: I haven't actually I didn't know that was an option, I'll give it a try, would definitely be neater!

Comment: ^ definitely far cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

So something like

```
    use \App\Clients\ClientMeta;

    class Attribute extends Model
    {

    protected $fillable = [...];

    protected static function boot()
    {
       parent::boot();

      static::saved(function ($attribute) {
            $meta = ClientMeta::firstOrCreate(['client_id' => $attribute->mem_id, 'meta_name' => 'profile_updated']);
            $meta->meta_value = time();
            $meta->save();
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, added as shown. Much cleaner! However, still only working on the Attribute model?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, visiually or n your log file at all?? Might mean the models not working or simialr

Comment: No nothing at all, everything updates. The event doesn't seem to fire at all and I've tried them all. This is the code that in this test should be calling the event `$lead =  \App\Clients\Lead::where('id', $data->lead_id)
        ->update($update);`

Comment: so have you tried to `dd($lead);`to see if it returns a success or fail etc, also within the Lead Model static::saved method write to the log, this will test if thats been fired too..

Comment: After testing it appears that ->update() doesn't fire any of the events. Strange! I'll just have to re-write!

Comment: Strange would have thought that one too :-) glad you sorted it though

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `parent::boot()` and `static` to method name

```
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        ...
```

***Make sure*** you're using the correct model events based on your CRUD method:

> **Events, as per Laravel**
>
> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into various
>   points in the model's lifecycle using the following methods: creating,
>   created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting, deleted,
>   restoring, restored. Events allow you to easily execute code each time
>   a specific model class is saved or updated in the database.

For example, when you update a model, you might want to do something like this:

```
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::updated(function ($attribute) { ... }
```

**Note, you should also add this to each model, versus app provider.**

Comment: there is no issue with registering the listeners outside of the model.

Comment: No, there's not. For me, it's more readability. Especially when your application starts getting bigger and you start adding more of these events. IMO